# How to skip a click in a web-page?

Tags: browser, web

Sometime, In some web pages, you always know the first click will pop-up ads. Is there a way to skip this click in a web page? I want the browser to click but not fetch the data of that click.

Comment: Configure browser to block popups from specific domain or just use adblockers

Comment: Also block the automatic page redirection in browser.

Comment: Firefox has the option ``dom.popup_allowed_events;change click dblclick mouseup pointerup notificationclick reset submit touchend``, which can help to avoid popups.